# Identify new objects in Amazon S3 at regular intervals

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have logs that are added to s3 bucket from various sources. 
I want to be able to read those logs base on interval, for example every 5 mins.
However, I don't want to scan all objects again, instead I will just need to get all of the new objects added since the last time my process ran. (In this case 5 mins ago)

For now, I solved this using s3 event. When there is a new file added to s3 it triggers lambda and saves the object name on dynamodb. Then, a cron job reads all the contents of that table in dynamodb, process it and deletes right after.

I feel like its an overhead. I just want call it directly from s3 using some sort of delta. I was wondering if this is supported.

Comment: Not not 'process' the file in the first Lambda function? Why are you wanting to batch it and then only process after a cron?

Comment: we could technically process when lambda is invoked but its not the best use case for us since the runtime might exceed the lambda time limits. In other words, each invocation has unpredictable runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using DynamoDB, you could:

- Configure the Amazon S3 Event to **create a message in an Amazon SQS queue** when a new file is received
- Your worker (presumably on an Amazon EC2 instance) can **poll the SQS queue for messages** (if it is waiting for a message, it can use Long Polling to query the queue so it doesn't ask too often)
- When a message is received, the worker can **process the file** and then **delete** the message from the SQS queue

This is a safe, **loosely-coupled process** that will handle potential failure in worker by keeping the notification in a queue. If the worker fails to process the message after a certain number of tries, the message can be automatically moved to a **Dead Letter Queue** for manual investigation.

Comment: This is the answer I came here to write :p

Comment: thanks, I had looked into this option as well. Though if there is a serverless alternative then we would consider it. But this approach seems to be the closest.

Comment: The serverless option would be to trigger an AWS Lambda function to process each file. However, if it is likely to hit a Lambda limit, then that won't work.

Comment: would you recommend fargate? Containerize my workers and schedule the task.

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid option. You could fire-up a container every hour (or whatever time period) and it would process all the messages in the queue. When it is finished, the task could terminate itself, similar to the EC2 suggestion above.